# The right way to share settings among modules

Tags: python

I have a project with 10 different python files. It has classes and functions - pretty much the lot.
I do want to share specific data that will represent the settings in the project between all the project files.

I came up with creating a `settings.py` file:

```
settings = {}
settings['max_bitrate'] = 160000
settings['dl_dir'] = r"C:\Downloads"
```

and then I import the class from every file.

Is there a more suitable way to do it?

Comment: I think there is the definitive way, pointed by Zigg: configuration files, commonly called ".INI files". Your use case is the very reason for their existence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm probably a little old-school in this regard, but in my latest project, I created a config file in `/etc`, then created a `config` module that uses [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) to read it in and make it available, and import that `config` module wherever I need to read settings.

Comment: I'm rediscovering their power. I think there should be a rule: EVERY parametric information on a system (also known as metadata) should be placed in configuration files, out of the source code. Actually: "Put abstractions in code, details in metadata": http://pragmatictips.com/38

Answer (score 1):

Your method sounds good to me, and has the advantage that you can easily change the implementation of the settings module, for example to use configuration files or the windows registry, or to provided a read only API.